# How to obtain (in a variable) the clipboard text with Robot framework (Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, clipboard

I need to verify the content of the clipboard after the push of an export button within a web page. It is possible to place that text in a variable ?

I have tried to paste the content (using Press Keys keyword) into an input field but it didn't really work; it did copy the text into that field but I wasn't able to get it in a variable (the log shows 'Empty').

Thanks a lot for your help !

PS: it's a Python environment

Comment: There is no such function in Selenium but Python library pyperclip should work.